# Change Div background on active tab - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I  have a set of 4 tabs which display content under a main header. Currently i can only show the same header in all tabs as they sit below the header.

Each one is linked by a ID which displays the tabs content. How can i make the background on the header change with Jquery when the link is clicked?

my code is below.

```
 <div class="my-header">

 </div>

 <div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="tab-list">
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#a1237as9123"> Tab 1 </a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#a1231239123">Tab 2 </a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#a1237522323">Tab 3 </a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#a1237123171">Tab 4 </a></li>
 </ul>

    <div class="content-1"></div>

    <div class="content-2"></div>

    <div class="content-3"></div>

    <div class="content-4"></div>

 </div>
```

Comment: As you are already using CSS to set the image, have different classes with different images and then you could use jQuery [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) with [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) or [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) - Try it out and if you got issues feel free to post the code and we have a look.

Comment: Set background image on the header using `$('.my-header').css('background-image', 'url(' + myBackgroundImageUrl + ')');`

Comment: I wrote the question wrong the problem is the <a> atribute.

Answer (score -1):

you need something like this:

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
    $('#changeMe').css('background-image', 'url(http://placehold.it/200x200/ff0000)');
})
```

Comment: OP is already using CSS to set the image, why would you use script to change css styles instead of using multiple classes and switch them? In general I would let CSS do what it suppose to do and let script focus on the rest.